# Substitute Multi Values Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a working function created(written by someone else) with the help of VBA to replace multiple strings, my problem is it replaces the 1st instance not the full value of the string, i will explain with an example.

Old Values

1. Car
2. Car Round Tyre

New Values

1. Bike
2. Bus

Now This Function can replace Car with Bike, but when it comes to "Car Tyre" it replaces Car with Bike and Ignores the "Tyre" Giving me Final Output as "Bike Round Tyre" but answer should be Bus

```
Function SubstituteMultiple(text As String, old_text As Range, new_text As Range)
Dim i As Single
For i = 1 To old_text.Cells.Count
    Result = Replace(text, old_text.Cells(i), new_text.Cells(i))
    text = Result
Next i
SubstituteMultiple = Result
End Function
```

This Function is very helpful but just needs to be polished.

Regards

Comment: Sort your `old_text` values by length, so you replace the longest values first.

Comment: Ahh Clever way to solve the problem (y), but i still think there would be a way out  by changing the code a little i suppose, i mean we just need to make vba consider the full cell value rather than just a part of the string. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If considering the full cell value is OK then:

```
Function SubstituteMultiple(text As String, old_text As Range, new_text As Range)

    Dim i As Single, Result as String
    Result = text
    For i = 1 To old_text.Cells.Count
        If text = old_text.Cells(i).Value Then
            Result = new_text.Cells(i).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    SubstituteMultiple = Result

End Function
```

Comment: Perfect :) ,Worked Like a Charm (y)
Thank you soo much